# Assigning and updating value for dynamically created input tags - jquery -Materialize autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, materialize

I am trying to build an invoice page where user search for product and details are auto-filled,

I am getting the values from the database to populate the Materialize dropdown and onAutocomplete to trigger the next events

If the user enters the Product code the value is being passed through ajax request and assigned to the corresponding values.

For single row, the code works perfect, 
The issue is when I add a new row and update the changes to any of the fields.

The issue I am facing: 
Values in all the rows are updated regardless of what's being clicked.

I am not sure how to bind response to the particular fields.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tab_logic" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead class=" purple accent-3 white-text text-darken-2">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center"> Product Code </th>
                            <th class="text-center"> Product Name </th>
                            <th class="text-center"> Qty </th>
                            <th class="text-center"> Price </th>
                            <th class="text-center"> GST </th>
                            <th class="text-center"> Total </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <input type="hidden" name="service_invoice_id" value="{{$orderid}}">
                        <tr id='addr0' class="addr0">
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input type="text" id="product_code" name='product_code[]'
                                            value="{{old('product_code')}}" class="autocomplete product_code"
                                            placeholder="Product Code">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input type="text" name='product_name[]' class="product_name"
                                            placeholder="Product Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input type="number" id="qty" name='product_qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty'
                                            class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0" required />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input type="number" id="price" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price'
                                            class="form-control price" step="0.00" min="0" required />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input type="number" name='gst[]' placeholder='GST %' class="form-control gst"
                                            step="0.00" min="0" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00'
                                            class="form-control total" readonly />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id='addr1' class="addr1"></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var name = {};
    var products = {!! $products->toJson() !!};
    //    var products_string = JSON.stringify(products);
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        name[[products[i].product_code]] = null;
    }
    // console.log(name);

    $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
        data: name,
        onAutocomplete: function(data) {
            var values = data.split(",");
            var product_code = values[0];
            console.log(product_code);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{ route('product-fetch')}}",
                data: { product_code: product_code },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("product_name").val(response.name);
                    $("input.qty").val(response.quantity);
                    $("input.price").val(response.price);
                    $("input.gst").val(response.tax);
                }
            }); //End of ajax
        } //End of OnAutocomplete
    }); //End of autocomplete
});

//This function created so that new rows could grab the autocomplete functionality.

function productFetch(e) {
    var name = {};
    var products = {!! $products->toJson() !!};
    //    var products_string = JSON.stringify(products);
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        name[[products[i].product_code]] = null;
    }
    // console.log(name);

    $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
        data: name,
        onAutocomplete: function(data) {
            var values = data.split(",");
            var product_code = values[0];
            console.log(product_code);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{ route('product-fetch')}}",
                data: { product_code: product_code },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $(".product_name").val(response.name);
                    $(".qty").val(response.quantity);
                    $(".price").val(response.price);
                    $(".gst").val(response.tax);
                }
            }); //End of ajax
        } //End of OnAutocomplete
    }); //End of autocomplete
}

//     $(document.body).ready(function() {
//     //Invoke the Autosearch
//     // productFetch();
//     //initiate select form
//     $(".gst_type").formSelect();
// });

$(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $("#add_row").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        b = i - 1;
        $("#addr" + i).html($("#addr" + b).html());
        //! will remove the selected element based on the class before being appended .
        $(".select-dropdown").remove();
        $(".tab_logic").append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
        //runs the method which will fetch the autocomplete
        productFetch();
        //initiate select form
        $(".gst_type").formSelect();
    });

    $("#delete_row").click(function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html("");
            i--;
        }
    });

    $("#tab_logic tbody").on("keyup change", function() {
        calc();
    });
    $("#gst").on("keyup change", function() {
        calc_total();
    });
});

//Logic for the calculation
function calc() {
    $("#tab_logic tbody tr").each(function(i, element) {
        var html = $(this).html();
        if (html != "") {
            var qty = $(this)
                .find(".qty")
                .val();
            var price = $(this)
                .find(".price")
                .val();
            var gst = $(this)
                .find(".gst")
                .val();
            var gst_total = (qty * price * gst) / 100;
            $(this)
                .find(".total")
                .val(qty * price + gst_total);
            calc_total();
        }
    });
}

//Calculates the total
function calc_total() {
    total = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sub_total").val(total.toFixed(2));
    tax_sum = (total / 100) * $("#gst").val();
    $("#tax_amount").val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
    $("#total_amount").val((tax_sum + total).toFixed(2));
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcryzsn4/4/)

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: tip: add this to codepen or Code Snippet to get answer.

Comment: You don't select the inputs of the correct row, but all the inputs with the classes `qty`, `price`, `gst`. On Autocomplete save the row where the autocomplete happened (sth. like `let $row = $(this).parent("tr")` ) and in your succes function only apply the values to the `$row`s input fields (`$row.find('.qty').val(response.quantity)`)

Comment: @AlexandrBiship Thanks - Added Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/qcryzsn4/4/

Comment: @Lapskaus I have added fiddle. I would appreciate if you could update me the changes and make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".product_name")` returns all the elements with this class in the page. You will need a parent element to target exact element that is required. So, you can for example get the `id` or `class` (whichever is present and unique) and append it to the beginning of the query.

**UPDATE:** Create custom `$this` and point to current `$('input.autocomplete')` as shown:

```
$("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
  data: name,

  onAutocomplete: function (data) { // replace with arrow function here 
    var values = data.split(",");
    var product_code = values[0];
    console.log(product_code);

    // create a custom $this to point to the current $("input.autocomplete")
    var $this = $(this)[0].$el;

    // Get the id of the table row
    var row_id = "#" + $this.parents('tr').attr('id') + ' '; // output: '#addr0 ' for the first row

    // Or get the tr element
    var $row = $this.parents('tr');

    console.log(row_id);
    console.log($row);

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{{ route('product-fetch')}}",
      data: { product_code: product_code },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        // Append the parent id to the beginning of your query
        $(row_id + ".product_name").val(response.name);
        $(row_id + ".qty").val(response.quantity);
        $(row_id + ".price").val(response.price);
        $(row_id + ".gst").val(response.tax);

        // or if you prefer this approach
        // $row.find(".product_name").val(response.name);
        // $row.find(".qty").val(response.quantity);
        // $row.find(".price").val(response.price);
        // $row.find(".gst").val(response.tax);

      }

    }); //End of ajax

  } //End of OnAutocomplete

}); //End of autocomplete
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k917w3a4/9/)

Comment: This most likely works! But it's kind of a strange way to select the row and the corrosponding child inputs.  Using the `$` - prefix in a variable name suggests that you are saving a DOM Element here, but you convert it to the `id`- String which breaks naming conventions and is kind of redundant. A better way would be to save the `var $row = $(this).parent('tr);` and use it directly in the selection `$row.find('.qty').val(response.quantity);`

Comment: Haha yes, I tripped. You're right, `$` prefix is actually redundant here since the variable contains a string. `$row.find('.qty').val(response.quantity);` is perfectly suitable for getting the job done, however my aim was to make minimal changes to the initial code that was posted. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out. Cheers :)

Comment: @tipos Thanks for the code, but when I console.log($row), I am getting #undefined

Comment: @Lapskaus var $row = $(this).parent('tr); console.log($row.find('.qty'.val()); bring me Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object].qty

Comment: `$row.find('.qty'.val()); ` you misplaced a closing bracket. It should be `$row.find('.qty').val();`

Comment: @Lapskaus Still getting undefined

Comment: maybe it is, are you sure that the $row variable is set in the scope you are using it in ? Without the whole code its just guessing.

Comment: Could you please take a look over the fiddle,

Comment: I even tried to add on change event to the $('input.autocomplete').on('change', function() {}, still I am getting undefined. I am completely clueless

Comment: It is `undefined` because the `input.autocomplete` is inside the `div.input-field` not the `tr` we need. So it returns an empty set.You should use `.parents()` method instead. It traverses up all the ancestors of an element. Also, I think arrow function would be more suitable here because we want to keep `$(this)` pointed to `$('input.autocomplete')`. I have updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: I tried parents the moment you stated parent yesterday, Still I was getting undefined. Tried the above code, same result - undefined

Comment: Really? Can you `console.log($(this))` and tell me what's the output?

Comment: I think $(this) is not bound to the onAutocomplete, coz when I run it on other parts the this works, Tried this code $(this).parents().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"}); inside #dd_row and it worked

Comment: It is returning the window object. $(this) is assigned depending on how you declare function. Have you tried changing to arrow function like this `onAutocomplete: (data) => {}` ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried this onAutocomplete: (data) => {} on my own. But I have copy pasted your answer and the console.log($(this)) result is from your code.

Comment: It will not work. `$(this)` inside the `.autocomplete()` is not pointing to `$(input.autocomplete)`.  I am trying to see what can be done here.

Comment: It is working now. Please see the code above. Cheers!

Comment: @tipos I wonder if you could help me with me question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65674742/250422 I guess `var $this = $(this)[0].$el;` might be the answer. But I am using pure javascript not jQuery. Any suggestions?